# ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender + Delete and Backspace not working for Ie11 but working ie11 compatible mode

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-11, ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender

I know lots of people asked this question but that is related to chrome. In my case, it's not working in IE11 also. ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender is being used in my project for TextBoxes. In Ie11 compatible mode, the backspace and delete keys are working but when we are using Ie11 native mode, these keys are not working for the textboxes. I tried to use some javascript i found for chrome but no help. Any idea? Pls help.

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue with the [Sample site](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx). Can you provide more info about your MaskedEditExtender setup?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  The only fix I have found thus far is to do one of the following:

Use JQuery Masks instead (not a fix, this is a complete replacement)
OR
Upgrade the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll (apparently the newest release does fix this problem, but that could have site-wide impact you might not want to invite)